# Make new array in controller by finding id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array with `Product Ids` and `Color HEX Codes`

**Input:**

```
@campaign.selectedproducts
```

**Output:**

```
["2,333333","1,333333",4,444444"]
```

**I'm trying to make a new array with all of the product data by finding it with id:**

```
@selectedgifts = @campaign.selectedproducts.collect [{|i| Product.find(i) }, |i| i.split(',').last]
```

**Array should output**

```
["Product Object, HEX code", "Product Object, HEX code"]
```

¿Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a good reason why you can't use a different data shape? something like:
`{ id: 2, color: "fff"}`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with group_by method like below:

```
@campaign.selectedproducts.group_by(&:color_code).transform_values{|val| val.pluck(:id).uniq}
```

Comment: It appears "selectedproducts" is an Array of Strings, so I am not certain what `color_code` or `pluck` are in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Converting Product object to string is not what you want i guess. So i suggest you storing each element as hash instead of string.

```
@campaign.selectedproducts.map do |string|
  id, hex_code = string.split(',')
  product = Product.find(id)
  { product => hex_code }
end
```

Edit: Or you can store each element as array like this:

```
@campaign.selectedproducts.map do |string|
  id, hex_code = string.split(',')
  product = Product.find(id)
  [product, hex_code]
end
```